# Number of columns/row in mask

Tags: matlab

Based on [this code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html#d126e253707):

```
x = 256*rand(1,4);
y = 256*rand(1,4);
x(end+1) = x(1);
y(end+1) = y(1);
bw = poly2mask(x,y,256,256);
imshow(bw)
```

Is there a way to define m and n instead of assigning 256 to both of them so the image will fit in case x and y are changed?

Comment: What are "m and n"? Do you mean the two sizes input to `poly2mask`? As in `poly2mask(x,y,m,n)`? If so, you could set `m=max(y)` and `n=max(x)`.

Comment: Thanks, I just rounded them with ceil to get the integer