# Rotate an object while keeping it dimensions - Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, rotation

I wish to rotate an object while keeping it dimensions using this code (based on this question: [Number of columns/row in mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77290257/number-of-columns-row-in-mask)):

```
close all;
clear;
clc;
  
x = 256*rand(1,4);
y = 256*rand(1,4);
x(end+1) = x(1);
y(end+1) = y(1);

BW = poly2mask(x,y,ceil(max(y))+50,ceil(max(x))+50);
imshow(BW)

LI = bwlabel(BW);
mea = regionprops(LI, 'Orientation');
RI = imrotate(BW, -mea(1).Orientation,'crop');
imshow(RI);

out = imtile({BW,RI});
imshow(out)
```

It sometimes work and sometimes not ("crop" results):
[image]

[image]

The imrotate "loose" bbox argument does not help in this case.

Loose results:

[image]

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Do no `"crop"`?

Comment: I tried "loose" (default) and "crop". Both does not work as "loose" changes the  dimensions

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is again? Can you be clear on what you mean by "dimnsion"?

Comment: I added another image ("loose" bbox) were th object size is not the same (BW vs. ,RI).

Comment: Define "size". It should be the same in area (in pixels). You either need to chose to crop the image, and risk it being outside (`'crop'`), or make the image bigger to fit the object after rotation (`'loose`').

Comment: With “loose” you get your desired result. It is just that you’re displaying the image in a way that the things in it look smaller. You cannot generally rotate an image, and not have it either crop the stuff in it or extend the image to be larger.